# Adding and removing records with a many to many relationship in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 2 ecto schema models that have a man_to_many relationship.

```
schema "Users" do

  many_to_many :locations, Location, join_through: "locations_users"
end

schema "Locations" do
  many_to_many :users, User, join_through: "locations_users"
end
```

So in my User.ex schema model file **how should I go about writing a function to add and also to remove a user**?

```
def add_location(location) do
  # ???
end

def remove_location(location) do
  # ???
end
```

In the ecto docs it says you shouldn't have to load all the associated data before adding/removing an association item, you can just set the association.  But since I am using a many to many, I'm not sure how I can just set the association since it is a join table only.

Comment: If you want to work with the whole association, you use `cast_assoc`, if you want to work with partial or transform before saving,  you use `put_assoc`. I think that is what is mentioned in the docs. Where is your user having the locations since it is to him you associate the given locations.?

Comment: I have a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369243/many-to-many-with-ecto-and-put-assoc-4